# ASP.NET MVC - Objects not passing through Controller to VIew

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my View:

```
  @{ 
      var categories = (List<C_Category>)Model.c;
  }

  @foreach (C_Category cat in categories)
  {
     <option value="@cat.C_Id">@cat.C_Name</option>
  }
```

And this in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Admin()
{
    using (var context = new sopingadbEntities())
    {
        List<P_Product> p = context.P_Product.OrderByDescending(x => x.P_Id).ToList();
        List<C_Category> c = context.C_Category.ToList();

        var ao = new AdminObj()
            {
                p = p,
                c = c
            };

        return View("Admin", new { c, p });
    }
}
```

But in my view I get an error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'c'

I'm sure I've been doing this way all the time, am I missing something?

Here is the addwatch:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Where is your class C_Category?  The error is due to C_Category not containing a property c.

Comment: The list of categories are passed in the view new {c, p} so i did Model.c to be the list of categories but it also passes List of P_Product

Comment: c is a single C_Category and not a list.  You have to get the c from {c,p} using a select.  You are trying to cast a single object to a list.  So you need List<C_Category> categories =  Model.c.Select(x => x.c).ToList();

Comment: i tried this from the mvc end context.C_Category.Select(x => x).ToList(); but still same error

Comment: Try : List<C_Category> categories = Model.Select(x => x.c).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u declare `AdminObj` as model in view than you have to pass ***var ao*** in return perameter

> or

currently u are returning `anonymous object` as model in return view which is not work in view as you casted

mention what you added as @model in view

### Answer extended:

Had to add this in the view as mentioned in this answer.

@model  ProjectWeb.Controllers.HomeController.AdminObj

And in Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        using (var context = new sopingadbEntities())
        {

            List<P_Product> p = context.P_Product.OrderByDescending(x => x.P_Id).ToList();
            List<C_Category> c = context.C_Category.ToList();
            var ao = new AdminObj()
            {
                p = p,
                c = c
            };

            return View(ao);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i changed it to 

[HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Admin()

        {

            using (var context = new sopingadbEntities())

            {



                List<P_Product> p = context.P_Product.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.P_Id).ToList();
  
              List<C_Category> c = context.C_Category.ToList();
  
              var ao = new AdminObj()
  
              {
  
                  p = p,
  
                  c = c
  
              };

  
              return View(ao);
  
          }
  
      }
but still no luck, is this what you mentioned to do